# Pinged usernames are not highlighted when followed by a comma

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Pretty straightforward, its what the title says.

Screenshot (courtesy of KronoS, who first noticed something was wrong):

[image]

The ping works in that the notification shows up, as well as the sound, but the name is not highlighted.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the regex matching that is used to add the `mention` class to the `<span>` element with the username. But it's way too complicated and obfuscated for me to look into that right now :P

Comment: @slhck, the strange part is that the rest of the ping works

Comment: That's because the ping itself is handled through the chat backend, not the frontend JavaScript.

Comment: @slhck, huh, good to know

Answer (score 3):

This was caused by [this rather huge change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139959/115866) to chat's handling of @replies. Fixed now, thanks for the report.